# Airbnb Airflow install error - Permission denied on ../dist-packages/

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I'm trying to install Airflow in Ubuntu 16.04. I get an error when I try:
pip install airflow

Here is the error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/ashim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil'
```

Comment: have you tried with sudo?

Comment: Thanks @Jesse. It was was sudo. I should have tried it before

Comment: If you use anaconda, I recommend that you can use the below URL.https://anaconda.org/phumke/airflow

Comment: The real question here is if airflow should be installed as root. Or should it be installed with a limited user (usually named airflow) with the `--user` flag. The airflow documentation is silent on this subject. This package is now called `apache-airflow` in pypi.

Answer (score 1):

And I'd like to mention that you should install other package such as sasl client if you want to use more subpackages(hive, hdfs, etc)

## conda install -c blaze sasl=0.2.1

## conda install -c conda-forge pure-sasl=0.3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install airflow
```

or

```
sudo pip install "airflow[celery,postgres]"
```

The second command lists the extra packages needed along with airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to the "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil" or to the enitre /usr/local/lib